# How to put a condition in 3d plotting

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have the following plotting question:

First I want to have 3D plot of Alpha respect to different values of `p` and `l` when we have

```
SuperStar[t] = (α*ρ*(t + l) - t)/(α*ρ - 1)

eq = (1 - α)^2 + (t^2*
      p)/(((SuperStar[t] - l)*(SuperStar[t] - l - 2*t))*A) == 0

Plot3D[ (31104-g[α]) /. 
  Solve[eq && 0.2 <= α <= 1, α], {l, 1, 5}, {p, 10, 40}]
```

where `t=12, l [2,5], ρ=0.8, p [10, 50], A=70`

```
g[α]= 2304 + 10*(230.4 - 1.6*l^2) + (30*(-1.1368*^-13 + 1.136*^-13*α + l*(-7.105*^-15 + 2.*l)*α^2))
  /(1.25 - 1.*α)^2 - (70*α*(360.0 - 2.5*l^2 - 576.*α + 230.4*α^2 + l*(-8.88*^-15 + 1.4*^-14*α 
  + 7.105*^-15*α^2)))/(1.25 - 1.*α)^2 + 100*((720. - 576.*α - 48.*l*α)/(1.25 - 1.*α)
  - 4*(0. + (112.49 + α*(-179.9 + 72.*α + l*(-15. + (11.99 + 0.5*l)*α)))/(1.25 - 1.*α)^2)) 
  + (288.*(-0.2 + α)*p)/(1 - α)
```

I want to see the effect of `l` and `p` on  `(31104-g[α])`, but I want to restrict `g[α]` so that when `α` is less than `0.2` Mathematica calculate `g[α=0.2]`

Now i get a graph where there is nothing for `α <= 0.2`.

I hope that I explained the problem clearly.

Comment: You have numerous undefined symbols in your first two lines of code.  Unless they are defined, Plot3D will return nothing but an empty graph, if that.  Please edit your Question to define all quantities, including `g`.

Comment: Dear @bbgodfery, thanks for the comment, I just defined them. hopefully my question is clear now.

Comment: Your equations contain both lower and upper case `L`.  Are these meant to be the same variable?  If so, please edit your equations accordingly.  If not, please provide the value for lower case `l`.  Additionally, g[α] is undefined.

Comment: Dear @bbgodfery, thanks again just edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t = 12; ρ = 8/10; A = 70;
SuperStar[t] = (α ρ (t + L) - t)/(α ρ - 1);
eq = (1 - α)^2 + (t^2 p)/(((SuperStar[t] - L) (SuperStar[t] - L - 2 t))*A) == 0;
soln = Solve[eq && 0 <= α <= 1 && 10 <= p <= 100 && 1 <= L <= 10, α,  Reals];

Plot3D[Evaluate[Max[2/10, α] /. soln], {L, 1, 5}, {p, 10, 40},
 BoxRatios -> 1, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 60, 
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 16] & /@ { "L", "p", "\[Alpha]"})]
```

[image]

```
ClearAll[g1];
g1[L_, p_] :=  With[{α = Max[2/10, α] /. soln}, 
   Simplify@Rationalize[(2304 + 10*(230.4 - 1.6*L^2) + 
       (30*(-1.1368*^-13 + 1.136*^-13*α + 
       L*(-7.105*^-15 + 2. L) α^2))/(1.25 - 1. α)^2 - 
       (70 α*(360.0 - 2.5*L^2 - 576. α + 230.4 α^2 + 
       L*(-8.88*^-15 + 1.4*^-14*α + 7.105*^-15*α^2)))/(1.25 - 1. α)^2 +
       100 ((720. - 576.*α - 48. L α)/(1.25 - 1. α) - 
       4 (0. + (112.49 + α (-179.9 + 72. α + 
        L*(-15. + (11.99 + 0.5*L) α)))/(1.25 - 1. α)^2)) + 
        (288.*(-0.2 + α)* p)/(1 - α))]];

Plot3D[31104 - g1[L, p], {L, 1, 5}, {p, 10, 40}, 
  BoxRatios -> 1, PlotPoints -> 60, AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 16] & /@ {"L", "p", "g1[L,p]"})]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @kguler, Thanks! could you just tell me why for larger value of p and l (if we change the interval to p[10, 60] and l[1,9]) , the graph doesnt show anything?

Comment: @Saman, try changing the definition of `soln` to `soln = Solve[eq && 0 <= α <= 1 && 10 <= p <= 60 && 1 <= L <=9, α,  Reals];`

Comment: I changed that but nothing is shown e.g. when L=8 for p>30. I'm confused because it should plot based on Alpha=0.2.

Comment: @Saman, you need to re-evaluate `g1` so that new solution for `alpha` is used in the defition of `g1`.

Comment: I did but still it gives me nothing. but thanks a lot it works perfectly for the interval I want (I might doing something wrong that i cannot get values for different intervals). one more question do you know if I can show the negative values in 3D plot differently (with different shade or have a transparent surface at {0,0,0}  )?

Comment: @Saman, you can use something like `Show[Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, MeshShading -> {Directive[Opacity[.7, Red]], Directive[Opacity[.7, Green]]}, Mesh -> {{0}}, BoxRatios -> 1], Plot3D[0, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.5, Orange]]]]`.

Comment: thanks you helped a lot! I really appreciate it. but which command gives that surface at 0? how can I put that command for my 3D that i asked earlier. Thanks again!

Comment: @Saman, `Plot3D[0, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.5, Orange]]]` gives a 3d plot of a constant function at 0. You can use `Show` to overlay it on top of other 3d plots. You can also do something like `Plot3D[{Sin[x y], 0}, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, BoxRatios -> 1,  Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Directive[Opacity[.5], Yellow]}]` but height-based coloring the first surface becomes more complex.

Comment: @Saman, you might want to edit your new post (re coloring negative values) with some clarifying detail/example to have it re-opened.

Comment: i face another problem regarding the 3D plotting. I get empty box for g1[L, r], I get the value/plot for Alpha but when I run for g1[L, r] gives me empty box. Any suggestion?

Comment: You mean `g1[L, p]` not `g1[L, r]`?

Comment: No, I defined p and now assume r as a variable. so I want to see how the function g1 behave respect to L and r. and r is on the interval [0, 1]. I get the values for Alpha but when I run g1[L, r] i get empty box. I can see the g1 is defined by only Alpha, L and r but I dont know why I get empty box

Comment: `r` plays the role of `rho` i presume?

Comment: can I somehow transfer the codes from mathematica to here to show what I'm doing?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: ,the function g1 is this: g1[L,rho] =2880 \[Rho] + (3600. (-0.2 + \[Alpha]) \[Rho])/(1 - \[Alpha]) + 
 10 (288 \[Rho] - 2 L^2 \[Rho]) + (
 2 L^2 (-10 + r) \[Alpha]^2 \[Rho]^2)/(-1 + \[Alpha] \[Rho])^2 - (
 200 (12 + (-12 + L) \[Alpha] \[Rho]) (-12 + (12 + 
       L) \[Alpha] \[Rho]))/(-1 + \[Alpha] \[Rho])^2 - (
 2 (110 - r) \[Alpha] \[Rho] (-L^2 + 
    144 (-1 + \[Alpha] \[Rho])^2))/(-1 + \[Alpha] \[Rho])^2

Comment: try something like `g2[L_, ρ_] := (2880 ρ + (3600 (-2/10 + α) ρ)/(1 - α) + 10 (288 ρ - 2 L^2 ρ) + (2 L^2 (-10 + r) α^2 ρ^2)/(-1 + α ρ)^2 - (200 (12 + (-12 + L) α ρ) (-12 + (12 + L) α ρ))/(-1 + α ρ)^2 - (2 (110 - r) α ρ (-L^2 + 144 (-1 + α ρ)^2))/(-1 + α ρ)^2) /. soln2` where `soln2` is the solution with your new values for the parameters. Also, you probably need to replace the two `r`s in this code with `rho`.